# How to make it post automatically without any command triggers

Tags: python, telegram, pyrogram

```
@bot.on_message()
def meme(_,message):
    res = requests.get('https://meme-api.herokuapp.com/gimme/Animemes').json()
    url = res['url']
    bot.send_photo(-1001436858099 , url)
    print(url)
```

How to make it post automatically without any command triggers?

Answer (score 0):

If you want your account/bot to post once with startup, you could use a context manager (`with:`) or programmatically with `app.start()` and `app.stop()`.

```py
app = Client()

# Either:
with app:
    app.send_photo()

# or
app.start()
app.send_photo()
app.stop()
```

---

If you want to schedule (ie, send at predefined intervals), you can use a scheduling library as laid out in the Documentation: https://docs.pyrogram.org/topics/scheduling